# resolve dns in my remote ubuntu server through my local ubuntu server

Tags: ssh, proxy

I have a  linux server at remote location and i am connected to it via openvpn.

I tried ssh into the server and found that i don't have internet access to it.

When asked about it to the remote site IT person, he is asking me to use proxy to provide internet access from my local pc .

Just need to redirect my dns to the remote site so dns could be resolved in the other end and internet starts working.

How is it possible.

I am new to this so having issues with it.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer also seems correct. But i found the easy way to go about it.

For that we will need pac manager v4.5.5.7. The lower version has bug. So better wget to get the package. 
steps:

1. Install squid in your ubuntu machine.

   ## apt-get install squid

Go to /etc/squid/squid.conf and edit the port as desired.

## nano /etc/squid/squid.conf

Default port is 3128 so better change it to another customized port. In my case i have used 55555.
Go to this line and edit as follows:

#Squid normally listens to port 3128
  http_port 55555

2.configure pac manager as requirement for ssh access:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDGh7.png)

3. Go to ssh options and then to Remote port forwarding and configure as below:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oBm6.png)
4. once this gets connected edit nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf
   nano /etc/resolv.conf 
   and put nameserver 8.8.8.8 (or whatever your requirement is)
5. Finally, run these commands:

   ## export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:55555

## export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:55555

This should work now. Try apt-get update and it works fine.

The command line for the above process would be :

## ssh -p 56789 -i "abcde.pem" -X -R 55555:localhost:55555 -l username 1.2.3.4

where  username is for the server we are accessing
       1.2.3.4 could be the ip address of the server 
       56789 is the ssh port number (22 if default is used)
       55555 is port that we use for squid (3128 if default is used)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess if it works, and you're happy with this then great!  But it sounds like your original problem was DNS was not resolving at the remotes site, and your solution is to . . . proxy ALL your traffic from the remote site thru your local site?

Comment: @BrandonXavier sorry i might not had described the problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a specific dns server on the other side of your openvpn for a short while, you can try to put that server in `/etc/resolv.conf`. If you really need to install  a dns-server on your local Ubuntu server, you may want to follow one of the many howto's that are available. I won't copy them into this answer; search for "bind9 howto" on google, and choose your favorite.

Comment: I can't change the dns server in /etc/resolv.conf because they have strictly asked not to touch the configuration. Searching through google, i guess the term is ssh tunneling. Still working on it.

Comment: You cannot, as you said, "redirect my DNS to the remote site" without changing `/etc/resolv.conf`.  That is exactly what that file is for. Even if you install bind9 as dns-proxy, you will need to have `resolv.conf` pointing to that proxy on your local host.

Comment: where do you mean i need to edit /etc/resolv.conf in my local ubuntu machine or on the remote machine? I guess i can't touch the configuration on the other side

Comment: `resolv.conf` is used to point the client machine to the DNS server. So in your case, that would be your local system.